# Photo rotates after updating to android 8.0 Oreo in nexus 5x

Tags: android, android-camera, android-8.0-oreo

A photo module, which were developed in my App, is running perfectly on all devices except for Nexus 5X after updating the Android version to 8.0 Oreo. On Nexus 5X, the photo module preview surface is flipped 180 degrees on X-axis and 180 degrees on Y-axis after taking the photo. Is there any way to resolve ?

Comment: are you sure it was working alright before

Comment: yes in 7.1 version

Comment: you need to rotate the image based on the exif flags,

Comment: but it was working fine before why it was that

Comment: Any updates on this? @AhmadArslan

Comment: not yet this issue still exists in my APP